How to avoid memory error for large dataarray
In Python I have a large xarray dataarray (da) of the shape
In [1]: da.shape
Out[1]: (744, 24, 30, 131, 215)

I need to perform the operation da = 10**da however, I'm running into a memory error

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 56.2 GiB for an array with shape (744, 24, 30, 131, 215) and data type float32

Is there a way to do the operation iteratively? I tried to manually loop but that gives the same error.
for ii in range(len(da[:,0,0,0,0])):
    da[ii,:,:,:,:] = 10**da[ii,:,:,:,:]

It works fine with smaller arrays e.g., (24, 24, 30, 131, 215).

Chunking the dataarray did the trick.
da = da.chunk({'dim0':50,'dim1': 24, 'dim2': 30, 'dim3': 131, 'dim4': 215})
da = 10**da


It sounds like your operation works fine on smaller arrays because they use less memory. But for an array of shape (744, 24, 30, 131, 215), you’re hitting a MemoryError due to the size of the data after the 10**da operation. I recently came across a similar issue and I used in placers to reduce the amount of storage used. You can also use Dask to convert into a Dask array and then work with each chunk which also may work if memory is an issue.
Using in placers:
for ii in range(da.shape[0]):
    da[ii, :, :, :, :] = 10**da[ii, :, :, :, :]

Using Dask:
import dask.array as dask
import xarray as xr

da = da.chunk({'dim_0': 1})

da = 10**da

# da.compute() or da.to_netcdf('result.nc')


The for ii in range... solution doesn't work (see my original post) as I'm still running into the memory error. Chunking the dataset works though.
